# How to modify data to be outputted in manifest.json from yarn build in pwa studio?

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio

I am new to PWA studio and Magento, so please bear with my question because I am a bit confused.

I already generated a custom PWA project in the PWA studio. However, when I performed the `yarn` build, the outputted `manifest.json` in artifacts (dist folder) contains `Venia` information like name, icons and etc. I want to modify the output instead of Venia info.

Is there a way of modifying it aside from manually overriding it? How?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

@Jean Kwon. manifest.json file is in venia-ui directory. maybe this plugin can be useful for your needs https://github.com/fooman/venia-ui-override-resolver

Thanks